# Have to replicate this layout in XAML, what controls would you use?

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I'm just beginning on figuring out what works best for layout/data display in XAML (WPF), and don't have the intuition yet of what controls, etc work well in certain situations.

- Nothing needs to be sorted or filtered, columns and rows are static
- Would using a datagrid or some combination of stackpanels/listboxes be best?
- I see the "tricky" parts as being adding the "skew adjusted" sub-heading and the separating lines between some of the columns, what would be some suggestions to add these?

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually use the standard Grid (not the DataGrid).  It seems ankward at the beginning but after you learn how to use it, you're gonna use it everywhere! :)

Here is an example to display your data (its not complete but you see the point):

```
<Grid x:Name="grdData" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Padding="10">Annualized Statistics</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">1Yr</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">2Yr</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">3Yr</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4">4Yr</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5">5Yr</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6">1st Half</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7">2nd Half</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="8">Incept</TextBlock>



        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Return</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">(4.81)</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">(2.25)</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3">1.01</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4">4.30</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5">(0.61)</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6">(18.75)</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="7">5.06</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="8">(7.48)</TextBlock>

        <Rectangle Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Fill="Black" Width="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Fill="Black" Width="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

    </Grid>
```